# Clinet-side read() gets random trailing characters to the message (TCP client-server using sockets)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Practicing C network programming: I am writing a simple TCP client-server application that is supposed to send a message (in a separate thread for each client) as a string from a the server to the client and print the message on the client side (latter on this will become a console shop app). I am sending the size of the message first, followed by the message itself using sockets, `write()` function. Server side:

```
void answer(void *arg) {
    struct thData tdL; 
    tdL= *((struct thData*)arg);

    // Welcome message
    char *initMsgToClient;
    getInitialMessage(&initMsgToClient);
    int len_initMsgToClient = strlen(initMsgToClient);

    // Returning message to client
    if ( write (tdL.cl, &len_initMsgToClient, sizeof(int)) <= 0 ) {
         printf("[Thread %d] ",tdL.idThread);
         perror ("[Thread] Error at write(): len_initMsgToClient to client.\n");
    }
    if (write (tdL.cl, initMsgToClient, len_initMsgToClient) <= 0) {
         printf("[Thread %d] ",tdL.idThread);
         perror ("[Thread]Error at write(): initMsgToClient to client.\n");
    }
    else
        printf ("[Thread %d] Message was sent with success.\n",tdL.idThread);

}

void getInitialMessage(char **paramMessage) {
    char *resultMessage = "Welcome to Console Shopper!";
    *paramMessage = resultMessage; 
}
```

And on the client side I am reading the size first and the message itself and printing it, but every time I run `./client` I get different random trailing characters to the message. Client side:

```
char welcomeMessageFromServer[512];
int lenWelcomeMsg;
// Reading size of first mesage: lenWelcomeMsg
if (read(sd, &lenWelcomeMsg, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading len welcome message from server.\n");
}
// Reading initial message from server: welcomeMessageFromServer
if (read(sd, welcomeMessageFromServer, lenWelcomeMsg) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading welcome message from server.\n");
    return errno;
}
printf("%s",welcomeMessageFromServer);
printf("\n");
```

For simplicity, I omitted to add the code for sockets and threads handling, most of it is from a tutorial so it should be correct. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the size of the message that is being sent/received.
My output with multiple runs for `./client`:

```
Welcome to Console Shopper!
Welcome to Console Shopper!�
Welcome to Console Shopper!������i0  
Welcome to Console Shopper!������UF+:
```

Some of the times it gets it right. What should I correct in order to get the right message all the times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Reading initial message from server: welcomeMessageFromServer
if (read(sd, welcomeMessageFromServer, lenWelcomeMsg) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading welcome message from server.\n");
    return errno;
}
printf("%s",welcomeMessageFromServer);
```

You have two issues here:

1. The `%s` format specifier is only for C-style strings. To make your received message a C-style string, you need to put a terminating zero byte on the end of it.
2. The `read` function does not ensure that it receives all the bytes requested. You need to check the return value and call it again if you didn't get the whole message.

Try a function like this:

```
ssize_t readAll (int fd, void *vbuf, size_t count)
{
     char *buf = (char *) vbuf;
     ssize_t read_so_far = 0;
     while (count > 0)
     {
         ssize_t ret = read(fd, buf, count);
         if (ret < 0)
             return ret;
         if (ret == 0)
             return read_so_far;
         count -= ret;
         read_so_far += ret;
         buf += ret;
     }
     return read_so_far;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
// Reading initial message from server: welcomeMessageFromServer
if (readAll(sd, welcomeMessageFromServer, lenWelcomeMsg) != lenWelcomeMsg) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading welcome message from server.\n");
    return errno;
}
welcoemMessageFromServer[lenWelcomeMsg] = 0;
printf("%s",welcomeMessageFromServer);
```

Comment: Should I do the same for reading any int or read() should be safe in case of integers?

Comment: You are ignoring the possibility that `read()` returns 0 if the peer disconnects gracefully. `if (ret < 0)` should be `if (ret <= 0)` otherwise you get stuck in an endless loop. The caller will have to decide how it wants to handle `readAll() < count` (as some protocols are OK with disconnects mid-read, ie FTP, while others are not).

Comment: @Elliad You should do the same thing for reading the `int`, good catch. Who knows, you might read just one byte. And read the comment above about the possibility of a normal disconnection causing `read` to return zero. (I made some possible updates to the code in my answer so that at least it won't endlessly loop.)

Comment: Did you omit initialization `ssize_t ret_so_far = 0`?